Double shower with no cold water from either fixture
I installed a new walk in shower with double heads, body sprayers and handheld sprayers. House is polybutylene pipe, transitioned to pex prior to shower valves. We also have a manibloc.
I am currently getting great flow from the fixtures with hot water, but no flow at all from cold. I initially thought blockage since fixtures are affected in both sides. After removing the cartridge, I get strong cold water flow to the valves, so I don't think a blockage is the problem.
Aside from 2 faulty cartridges on newly installed valves (which seems unlikely), is there anything else that could be the issue?

Cartridge or connection backwards, causing the "anti-scald" feature to attempt to make it colder, but actually make it hotter due to hot going to cold side? So it's too hot and moving the valve to "add cold" but that's actually making it "all hot" which makes the thermal component try harder to make it all cold, but...
